# Issue in Jenkins build not Eclipse

Tags: maven, jenkins

In jenkins there are two project A and B both are maven project and both the projects are running fine when do clean and install from the STS.
However,when the same project is refered in jenkins as a maven project.Its not able to resolve the dependency of Project A.

When I put explicitly the Dependency in jenkins .m2 folder repository it works

Projects A jar is created here.

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.XYZ.k</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>abc</name>
```

Referring in Project B POM like below.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.XYZ.k</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>       
     Problem is coming like not able to resolve dependency:
enter code here
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project rpg4xref: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xyz.xa:B:jar:13.2.00-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.xyz.abc:abc:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in file:/// was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of localRepsoitory has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Have you checked if the dependency is available on the repository verified by Jenkins during the build?

Comment: I have checked that this was not lying in jenkins repository. I deployed the Project A in jenkins then this is available in jenkins repository. 

Is it right way ?. Though its reolved now by doing deployement of Project A because Project B uses it?.

Comment: Usually when you trigger a build, depending on your jar, you have a goal to deploy it to some artifactory (using `mvn deploy` for example), probably the build you ran published the artifact in there. The dependencies that are needed in your package must be published in the artifactory. Also if you have a lot of modules, you must run all the builds in order (B depends on A, so A needs to be built first)